# Linker Issues VS2015. LNK2019 and LNK2001 unresolved external symbol

Tags: c++, visual-studio, linker, visual-studio-2015, constraint-programming

I am trying to extend my knowledge of constrain programming and I want to build a simple example using google's [or-tools](https://github.com/google/or-tools#readme) in VS2015.

However I am constantly nagged by those linker errors. LNK2019 and LNK2001. Why is linking in VS so darn hard.

Google's [or-tools](https://github.com/google/or-tools#readme) comes in a perfect folder, with an include subfolder and lib subfolder with one single .lib file.

I have added Additional Library Dependencies.

```
Configuration Properties -> Linker -> General Additional Library Dependencies : C:\PATH\or-tools.VisualStudio2013-64b\lib
```

Set the Input under the Linker properties section.

```
Configuration Properties -> Linker -> Input Additional Dependencies : ortools.lib
```

Infomed VC++ where the include directory is.

```
Configuration Properties -> VC++ Directories : C:\PATH\or-tools.VisualStudio2013-64b
```

However it is still throwing link errors when building the solution. What am I missing here.

Thanks in advance.

**edit:**

spelling

Comment: Are you attempting to use Visual Studio 2013 binaries with Visual Studio 2015?

Comment: Uhm Yes, but It does not work under VS2013 either. I have the feeling that I am missing a step in the static library adding process. If I am trying any other .lib the #pragma comment(lib, "mylib") is not sufficient either.

Comment: Answering your question could be easier if you provided those link error messages here or at least through at link.

Comment: Hold on, I am trying to link an old binary to a new version... fml

Comment: Libraries are searched for in the "Library Directories" not in the "Include Directories".

Answer (score 2):

Since the VS2013 and VS2015 compiler versions are incompatible, you have to [build the lib from source](https://developers.google.com/optimization/installing#installing-from-source). Though beware that this might entail a bit more work when linking with VS2015. Specifically I've had to manually resolve the following issues:

1. Change `protobuf-3.0.0-beta-1` to `protobuf-3.0.0-beta-2`(bonus. not really necessary)
2. gflags 2.1.2 failed to compile due to a conflict of names around `snprintf`. To resolve this download the latest gflags version from GitHub and overwrite the one in `%OR_TOOLS%\dependencies`
3. Look up all VS solution files (.sln) in `dependencies\sources\cbc-2.9.7` and convert to VS2015 format by simply double clicking them and following the instructions.
4. Add the following code to `makefiles\Makefile.port`

`ifeq ("$(VisualStudioVersion)", "14.0")
    VISUAL_STUDIO=2015
    VS_RELEASE=v140
    VS_COMTOOLS=140
  else
  ...
  endif`

5. Replace `Visual Studio 12 2013` with `Visual Studio 14 2015`

Rerun `make third_party` after each step.

Or you can just [download](https://drive.google.com/folderview?id=0Byc7L-plgFbBWm9meDM4RHAzYXc&usp=sharing) the end result, linked on Windows 10 x64 VS2015 update 1. I've included the whole folder after running `make third_party && make cc`.